# composer autoload doesn't load the file properly

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have problems with auto loading the files, I tried to find some solution but with no luck. Here is my file structure:

```
my-site
- src
- - app
- - - core
- - - - App.php
- vendor
index.php
composer.json
```

Here is my my composer.json

`"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\":"src"
        }
    }`

Here is my App.php file:

```
namespace App\Core;
class App {}
```

and now, if I try (into index.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Core\App;
var_dump( class_exists('App') );
```

Where I'm wrong ?

Thanks.

I found my problem, the problem in my case was into the dump-autoload, I tried like this:

```
composer dumpautoload -o
```

and now works, thanks guys!

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload` to regenerate the autoloader after adding the autoload config? Also, post the entire `autoload` section of your composer.json as there may be other problems.

Comment: Oh, also that should be `App.php`. Case-sensistive.

Comment: @Sammitch I run dump autoload, and also the class name and filename is App.php (sorry, I have edited my question).

Comment: Where in your directory structure is your composer.json located?

Comment: @Sammitch composer.json file is into root directory of the website (my-site), you can check my edited question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your App.php has the following namespace based on your directory structure

```
<?php
namespace App\Core;

class App {
....

}
```

then

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\":"src"
    }
}
```

Basically it's saying package **App** starts at root of **src** folder.

```
my-site
- src
- - app
- - - core
- - - - App.php
- vendor
composer.json
index.php (the file that is doing the autoload if not at this level you need to adjust the file path for loading)
```

Comment: thanks, but with no luck still... You can check y edited question with full folder/file/class structure (case-sensitive), and also I run dump-autoload after any changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem, the problem in my case was into the dump-autoload, I tried like this:

```
composer dumpautoload -o
```

and now works, thanks guys!